# Getting the values of the collection from Expression with Lambda - .Contains

Tags: c#

### Getting the values of the collection from Expression with Lambda - .Contains

I'm trying to get all values from the collection that contains a member in IQueryable. However, it seems that different collections behave differently.

Consider the following listing:

```
 var sampleData = new List<MyClass> { new MyClass { MyMember = "a" }, new MyClass { MyMember = "b" }, new MyClass { MyMember = "c" } };
 IEnumerable<string> samplEnumerable = new List<string> { "b", "a" };
 List<string> sampleList = new List<string> { "b", "a" };
 var resultTest1 = sampleData.AsQueryable().GetCalledMemberAndValidValues(x => (new[] { "b", "a" }).Contains(x.MyMember));
 var resultTest2 = sampleData.AsQueryable().GetCalledMemberAndValidValues(x => sampleList.Contains(x.MyMember));
 var resultTest3 = sampleData.AsQueryable().GetCalledMemberAndValidValues(x => samplEnumerable.Contains(x.MyMember));
```

`Extension Method`

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
   public static dynamic GetCalledMemberAndValidValues<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
      string parameterName = string.Empty;
      ArrayList values = new ArrayList();
  MethodCallExpression node = (MethodCallExpression)predicate.Body;

  if (predicate.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Call)
  {
    if ((node.Method.Name == "Contains"))
    {
      Type valueType = null;
      foreach (var obj in node.Arguments)
      {
        if (obj.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess && ((MemberExpression)obj).Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Parameter)
        {
          parameterName = ((MemberExpression)obj).Member.Name;
        }

        // The below block is valid for array[];
        if (obj.NodeType == ExpressionType.NewArrayInit)
        {
          values.AddRange(((NewArrayExpression)obj).Expressions);
        }

        // The below block is valid for IEnumerable<T>;
        if (obj.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess && ((MemberExpression)obj).Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        {
          var value = (((MemberExpression) obj).Member as FieldInfo).GetValue(((obj as MemberExpression).Expression as ConstantExpression).Value);

          values.AddRange((ICollection)value);
        }
      }

      // The below block is valid for List<T>;
      if ((predicate.Body as MethodCallExpression).Object != null)
      {
        var obj = (MemberExpression)(predicate.Body as MethodCallExpression).Object;
        var value = (obj.Member as FieldInfo).GetValue((obj.Expression as ConstantExpression).Value);
        values.AddRange((ICollection)value);
      }
    }
  }

  return new { parameterName, values };
}
}
```

`MethodCallExpression` object stores the property name `MyMember` in the field `Arguments` and the value gets stored in the field `Object`.

`MethodCallExpression` object stores both the property name `MyMember`and its value in the field `Arguments`.

As you can see, all three examples produce the same result.

However, i am not happy with having to deal with each collection type differently.

How to generalise this and get the property name and value from the same field of the `MethodCallExpression`?

Answer (score 1):

This will get it done:

```
public static dynamic GetCalledMemberAndValidValues<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    var methodCall = predicate.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    Expression collectionExpression = null;
    MemberExpression memberExpression = null;
    if (methodCall != null && methodCall.Method.Name == "Contains")
    {
        if (methodCall.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Enumerable))
        {
            collectionExpression = methodCall.Arguments[0];
            memberExpression = methodCall.Arguments[1] as MemberExpression;
        } else {
            collectionExpression = methodCall.Object;
            memberExpression = methodCall.Arguments[0] as MemberExpression;
        }
    }

    if (collectionExpression != null && memberExpression != null)
    {
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(collectionExpression, new ParameterExpression[0]);
        var value = lambda.Compile()();
        return new { parameterName = memberExpression.Member.Name, values = value };
    } 

    return null;
}
```

You can't make it completely generic. These two methods:
`(new[] { "b", "a" }).Contains`
`samplEnumerable.Contains`

Are actually calling `Enumerable.Contains(source, x.Member)`.

`sampleList.Contains(`

calls `sampleList.Contains(x.Member)`.

Note the number and order of arguments. 
So while they look the same when writing the code, you're actually referencing different methods. This will check which contains method is being called, and then figures out which argument is the collection, and which argument is the member expression.